# Update a website that already published and always have online users?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am going to develop an asp.net website. My problem is think that now my site is published on the internet. 100 Users are already logged to my website. And they opened customer registration form in the website. So we know that when user log to a website he is sending a get request for the specific page. Then the server is sending that page in HTML format and it destroy the page from the server side. 
So think that after server sent the customer registration form to the user I am going to do a update to my website. What I am doing is removing some input fields from the customer registration form. So imagine that at the user's end he can see 10 textboxes but my updated version will only contain 5 textboxes. So now what? What is going to happen? Is this lead to an error?

I just took a small example. Think that this situation occur in the middle of a transaction.

What is the scenario that use to update a website that already published and always have online users?.

Comment: Post maintenance information/redirect to maintenance site; Shut down the main site; update site; recycle; then old requests will be invalid and people will just start again and request information from the server. It's nothing complex or out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

Just Recycle the Application pool, this will make a new request for the online users. Like a fresh start.